# font size with tikzset and tikzscale not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikzscale

I want to set the font family and size for all pgf/tikz figures in my preamble. But when I use tikzscale, then this is ignored. Can anyone help?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={font=\sffamily\huge}}

\begin{document}
\input{figure.tikz} %here \sffamily\huge is working

\includegraphics[width=12cm]{figure.tikz} %here \sffamily\huge is ignored
\end{document}
```

with the figure file

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0) {Foobar};
\draw[dashed] (-5,0) -- (5,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I think you'll find that any global settings are ignored.

Comment: No, if I use a pgf plot as the figure file, then the font setting is NOT ignored. The problem is only in the tikz "pictures".

Answer (score 2):

The class `every picture` is reset by `tikzscale`.

Looking at the code we can see

> ```
> \NewDocumentCommand{\tikzscale@prepareTikzpicture}{}{%
> \tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=\tikzscale@scale,every picture/.style={}}}%
> }
> ```

A workaround is to use another style for this. Here is an example.

The main file :

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1cm,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\tikzset{test/.style={font=\sffamily\huge}}

\begin{document}

  \input{tikzscale_font.tikz} %here \sffamily\huge is working

  \includegraphics[width=12cm]{tikzscale_font.tikz} %here \sffamily\huge is working now too

\end{document}
```

and the `tikzscale_font.tikz` :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[test]
  \node at (0,0) {Foobar};
  \draw[dashed] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what side-effects this might have, but based on [Kypm's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220541/), you could add the following to you preamble, which works without modifying the code for the `tikzpicture` itself:

```
\makeatletter
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\tikzscale@prepareTikzpicture}{}{%
    \tikzset{every picture/.append style={scale=\tikzscale@scale,every picture/.style={}}}%
  }
\makeatother
```

[image: foobar scaled]